# How Work PopViewController in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I Want a knowledge about a popToViewController. i am a using a navigation based application, in each view i am using a 2 UIButton as forward and backward views. And i am using pushViewController to move next view, as a hole program i am using 4 view Sequence A,B,C,D.
when i click a forward button in A View it push to next View(means B). and again their a forward button, again i click to that forward button, it move to C View. but i want to move back to B view and again in B View when i click the backward button it move back to A View.

Please Someone Help Me..
thanks in advance..

Comment: PopViewController does n't work on iPhone, it only works on iPad.

Comment: @NikhilBansal: He is not talking about `UIPopoverController`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have declared the navigation controller in the AppDelegate and have set the navigation controller as the root view controller.
Just in case if you haven't n assuming that you started with a single view application.

the appdelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
ViewController *objViewController;

UINavigationController *objectNavigationController;
}
```

n the .m file

```
objViewController =[[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
objectNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objViewController];
self.window.rootViewController=objectNavigationController;
```

and just give the code similar to this for the button action , it navigates to the next view controller

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender

{
secondViewController *newObj = [[secondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newObj animated:YES];
```

}

n as for the button to navigate to previous page, the navigation controller provides a button which works like a back button.

and if you really want pop with a button

```
-(IBAction)popBack:(id)sender
{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

this will do :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: its working but when i move to C View and click a backward button it only come back view. but i again click the backward button in B View it give Me Exception EXE_BAD_ACESS

Comment: so your saying that when you clicked back from C , you reached B , and again if you click it , it shows bad acces???  Thats cause the button action is set on that view controller to pop it, ie the present view controller, but you can choose to set it to pop to a specific view controller or to the root view controller if you want, and have you placed the button in each of the view controllers and written the code for it? if not its not bound to work.

Comment: so now how we can do that? because this problem is come to my project. and all project is completely done. but just only this thing is give me problem. so please help me..

Comment: sorry for taking too long to reply bro , was going back home 
have you written the codes for the button actions in each of the view controllers?? to push view controller n to pop them aswell on their respective buttons?? try posting just the code you used , i'll try to help you out

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );    
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(BackClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];


    
}
-(void)BackClicked:(id)sender
{
    
    [self popToViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
}

Comment: the back button is appearing on the navigation bar right? , just try using :

(void)BackClicked:(id)sender {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }

Comment: check the first code i've posted , it will work if you have a navigation controller initialized , do check your codes again bro the way i've answered, you may have missed something out something, if you just want it to be a back button , you really don't need to set an image for it, just try using my code and see

Comment: try this code :


UIBarButtonItem *buttonZ = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     
    
    buttonZ = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(BackClicked:)];
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=buttonZ;

Answer (score 0):

here is an opensource implementation for popover in iPhone.

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-popover-api-for-iphone-wepopover.html

code @github
https://github.com/PaulSolt/WEPopover

Comment: Thanks For That, But Small mistake is that spelling mistake is their. now the question is ok.